# Symmetric Functions on Infinite dimensions

Tags: functions, infinite-product, symmetric-functions

Suppose $X = [0,1]^\infty$. Given $x\in X$ denote by $x(i,j)$ for $i<j$ by the element obtained by swapping the components $x_i$ with $x_j$ in $x$. A function $f:X\rightarrow\Bbb R$ is symmetric if $f(x)=f(x(i,j))$ for all $x$ and $i<j$.
It is weakly increasing if it is increasing along the diagonal, so for $a,b\in [0,1]$ with $a>b$ we have $f(a,a,a...)>f(b,b,b,...)$.

Is it true that for every such function (symmetric and weakly increasing) and for $x\in X$ there is some $a\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=f(a,a,a,...)$?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$f(x) = 2\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n - \liminf_{n \to \infty} x_n.$$

Comment: Yes, this answers the original question. I did forget to mention that the function is  increasing on the diagonal, which is not satisfied by the $f$ you propose.

Comment: @RexNolan: How about now? :)

Comment: Do all functions $f:X \to \Bbb R$ satisfying symmetry, monotonicity ($x\gt y$ implies $f(x)\geqslant f(y)$), strictly increasing on the diagonal also satify the property of the original question: for each $x\in X$ there is $a\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=f(a,a,a,...)$?

Comment: You should probably edit this into your question, or ask a new question, so that people besides me will see it.  I am not sure how many variations I have the energy to think about.  The general idea I'm suggesting, though, is that one way to make a function symmetric is to have it only look at the "tail" of the sequence.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I got that part and agree. "Limit functions" are characterized by permutation invariance among other things. I will think about the question myself, before going down the rabbit hole but thanks for your very quick reply to a not very well formed question.